# strange back button behavior - my app closes instead of popping back-stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, adb

In my app I have 3 activities (I have more but lets stick with 3 for simplicity), lets call them A B and C where A is the main activity.

Activities B and C could be accessed multiple times from various locations in my app so in order not to overload the back stack and get `outOfMemoryException`, I launch these activities using the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

However recently I started to experience some strange behavior from the back stack/back button where the back button closes the app instead of popping the top activity.

Here is an example of what is happening:

1. user open app - back stack is "A"
2. user opens activity B - back stack is "A B"
3. user opens activity C - back stack is "A B C"
4. user opens (**not** pressing back button) activity B again - back stack is "A C B"
5. user presses back button

**Expected behavior:** back stack should be "A C" and activity C should be visible on the screen again.

**Actual behavior:** app closes.

I have confirmed the state of the back stack with `adb shell dumpsys activity` and before pressing the back button the stack indeed looks like "A C B".

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix this?

### edit

my device is LG V30 and running API 25.
I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695522/puzzling-behavior-with-reorder-to-front). apparently this exists since API 19! I do not wish to start messing and using hacks with the back stack and looking for another solution.

### edit 2

here is how i launch a new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityFavoriteShows.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.somepackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".pojos.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityMain">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivityShowInfo"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivitySeasons"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityCast"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityCrew"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivitySearch"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityFavoriteShows"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivitySettings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

        <service
            android:name=".services.ServiceReadWrite"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When the app closes - do you get some error in the logcat?

Comment: You don't have any ``NEW_TASK`` involved anywhere? Can you show us your manifest, what activity flags are defined there? And post your full Intent code up to the ``startActivity`` call

Comment: @or_dvir Can you please check my answer it may be help full to solve your issue.

Comment: @Grisgram please see "edit 2"

Comment: @or_dvir This behavior exists in all devices or in that particular device (LG V30)??

Comment: @Chandrakanth i have only tested on this device, but it looks like this is a bug since API 19...